# Ignore touch in overlay app

Tags: java, android, overlay

i create a system overlay app using [this](https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256) way

but i have a problem .... when i move my button to corner of screen, i can't touch system's view like **Call** button in the following image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJlZ.png)

how can i disable any touch in my button ? ( ignore my view's touch and touch system's view )
in somewhere i find this code but it isn't work

```
bl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Return `false` from `onTouch`, the event will be captured by the underlying layer, if any...

Answer (score 0):

Always visit developer.android.com first, it's really well documented with fundamental concepts.

The `onTouch` method will pass the event to the layer below it, if it returns `false`.
**If you've extended a default touchable View class**, you should use `return super.onTouch()`

Here's the link you're looking for:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: @Arash I went through the source code... The **sole intention** of the program you've found is to create a system overlay... Why would you want to make that overlay pass the touch event to the system view. That's contradictory, don't you think?